# How to fix choppy audio and Wi-Fi problems with Bluetooth speaker on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, audio, osx-lion, bluetooth

I have a Creative D200 Bluetooth speaker that I use with my 2011 MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Lion. The speaker more or less works as a Bluetooth audio device, but I run into two problems seemingly randomly.

1. The audio will hesitate or become choppy. This seems to be mostly resolved if the computer is very close to the speaker (1ft instead of 4ft).
2. The Wi-Fi on the MacBook will stop working (all requests time out) and will only work again if I disconnect the Bluetooth speakers.

How can I go about diagnosing / fixing this problem? What could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you know someone who owns the latest version of Mac OS X, which is Mountain Lion 10.8.4 as of this writing, boot your MacBook Pro off of that (maybe from an external drive or via Target Disk Mode) and see if the problem reproduces under the latest OS.  It may be that you're running into some driver bug that Apple finally figured out and fixed after your older version of Mac OS X was discontinued.